# Magento 1.9 attributes in cart

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, magento-community

I need to find a way to access attributes in a cart, I am able to do it in a product view with this code

```
public function getProductInfo() {
        $product = $this->getCurrentProduct();
        $attributes = $product->getAttributes();

        $productSet = array(
            'id' => $product->getId(),
            'sku' => $product->getSku(),
            'name' => $product->getName(),
            'price' => $product->getPrice(),
            );

        foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
            if ($attribute->getIsVisibleOnFront()) {
                $attributeCode = $attribute->getAttributeCode();
                $label = $attribute->getFrontend()->getLabel($product);      
                $value = $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
                $productSet[$label] = $value;
            }
        }
        return $productSet;
    }
```

It works perfect and pulls all attributes, however when I try to do it in cart with this code

```
public function getCartInfo() {
        $cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart');
        $quote = $cart->getQuote();
        $counter = 1;
        $outArray = array();

        if ($quote && $quote->getId()) {
            $outArray = array(
                'items_count' => $cart->getItemsCount(),
                'items_qty' => $cart->getItemsQty(),
                'customer_id' => ($quote->getCustomerId()) ? $quote->getCustomerId() : 0,
                'grand_total' => $quote->getGrandTotal(),
                'base_grand_total' => $quote->getBaseGrandTotal(),
                'subtotal' => $quote->getSubtotal(),
                'base_subtotal' => $quote->getBaseSubtotal(),
                'store_id' => $quote->getStoreId(),
                'currency_code' => Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode(),
                );

            foreach ($cart->getItems() as $product) {
                $productId = $product->getProduct()->getId();
                $productPrice = $product->getProduct()->getPrice();
                $attributes = $product->getProduct()->getAttributes();
                $outArray['qty' . $counter] = $product->getQty();
                $outArray['id' . $counter] = $productId;
                $outArray['Price' . $counter] = $productPrice;
                foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
                    if ($attribute->getIsVisibleOnFront()) {
                        $attributeCode = $attribute->getAttributeCode();
                        $label = $attribute->getFrontend()->getLabel($product);      
                        $value = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId)->getAttributeText($attributeCode);
                        $outArray[$label . $counter] = $value;
                    }
                }
                $counter++;
            }
        }
        return $outArray;

    }
```

it only pulls in some, the weird part is if I use

```
$value = $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($product->getProduct());
```

it pulls in 3-4 attributes, and all others are No, then if I use

```
$value = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId)->getAttributeText($attributeCode);
```

it pulls in 3-4 other attributes, but ones previously available through getValue are now false

So I need to somehow figure out how to pull in all attributes visible in frontend

Any ideas?

Thanks!!

Comment: `$value = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);`

`Print_r($value->getData());`

Answer (score 3):

Try to add the missing attributes in your models config.xml

```
<global>
...
    <sales>
        <quote>
            <item>
                <product_attributes>
                    <yourmissingattribute/>
                </product_attributes>
            </item>
        </quote>
    </sales>
 .....
</global>
```

Comment: Hi @schasiepen, thank you for above. But just a newb question, since I've not worked with config.xml before, where do I find it? I have one in the extension folder, and one in the app/etc/config.xml. in the app/etc config I see global -> models should I put it into there? so far all I have in there is varien, core & core_resources